# Suppose $E$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$. Show that the projection map $\pi :E \to M$ is a surjective smooth submersion.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

> Suppose $E$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$. Show that the projection map $\pi :E \to M$ is a surjective smooth submersion.

Since $E$ is a smooth vector bundle for each $p \in M$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $p$ such that $\varphi: \pi^{-1}(U) \to U \times \Bbb R^k$ is a diffeomorphism and that $\pi_1 \circ \varphi = \pi$.

In order for $\pi$ to be a smooth submersion the differential $d\pi_p : T_p E \to T_{\pi(p)} M$ must be surjective.

Since we have the characterization $\pi_1 \circ \varphi = \pi$ we get that $$d\pi_{p} = d(\pi_1 \circ \varphi)_p = d\pi_{1_{\varphi(p)}} \circ d\varphi_{p}.$$

Now I need to show that $d\pi_{1_{\varphi(p)}}$ and $d\varphi_{p}$ surjective maps in order to conclude the proof.

Since $\varphi$ is a diffeomorphism we have that $\varphi^{-1}$ is a smooth bijection. So defining $d\varphi^{-1}_{q} : T_{q}(U \times \Bbb R^k) \to T_p \pi^{-1}(U)$ we have that $$d\varphi_p \circ d\varphi^{-1}_{q} = d(\varphi \circ \varphi^{-1})_{q} = d(id)_{q}$$

so $d\varphi^{-1}_{\varphi(p)}$ is an inverse for $d\varphi_p$ and so it's bijective and in particular surjective.

Similarly for $d\pi_{1_p}:T_p(U \times \Bbb R^k) \to T_{\pi_1(p)}U$ define $d\iota_{U_q} : T_qU \to T_{\iota_U(q)}(U \times \Bbb R^k)$ where $\iota_U:U \to U \times \Bbb R^k$ is the right inverse of $\pi_1$. Then we get that $$d\pi_{1_p} \circ d\iota_{U_q} = d(\pi_1 \circ \iota_U)_q=d(id)_q$$ which by same reasoning makes $d\pi_1$ surjective.

Is there some problems with the proofs for the surjectivities for these differentials? I'm not very confident about them.

Comment: I'd say it's okay!

Comment: I also think it's OK. I would like to propose another proof that does not use local trivializations. By definition, a tangent vector $v \in T_pM$ can be thought of the derivative at $0$ of a smooth path $\gamma \colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to M$. Lift $\gamma$ into a path in $\tilde{\gamma}\colon (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \to E$ by, e.g, $\tilde{\gamma}(t) = 0 \in E_{\gamma(t)}$ (that is, lift it with the zero section), then obviously, $\pi\circ \tilde{\gamma} = \gamma$. Taking the derivative at zero of this last expression now concludes the proof.

Comment: $\pi$ is surjective and smooth by definition, so you only need to show that the differential in each point is surjective, right?

Comment: @Didier I think your proof only shows that the differential of $\pi$ is surjective at points in the image of the zero section.

Comment: @ClaraB. Oh yes, you're right. Nevermind, you can lift it at other points too with a slight modification of my argument.